# create custom annotation animation ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, mapkit, mkannotation

I want to create custom annotation animations like in this app:- [Easy Taxi iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/easy-taxi-book-a-taxi-app/id567264775?mt=8). In this app when the user is dragging the map, annotation is lifted a little. Then when dragging is stopped, it falls down from the lifted position with a nice animation.

So far i came to know that, I can use a static image in the center of my screen to show the movement on the map, &  when i stop dragging the view(map) i have to build a custom animation for the annotation view.

So far i have implemented this code by which i am manipulating an Image to be hidden or shown on the map View in the center of the screen.

```
    -(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [super touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];

    for (UITouch * touch in touches) {
        CGPoint loc = [touch locationInView:self.mapView];
        if ([self.mapView pointInside:loc withEvent:event]) {
            self.mapKitAnnotationimageView.hidden=NO;
            imageCheck=NO;
        }

    }
}
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    imageCheck=NO;
    self.mapKitAnnotationimageView.hidden=YES;
}
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated{
    if (!imageCheck) {
        self.mapKitAnnotationimageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"location"];
        imageCheck=YES;
    }
}
```

Any help regarding the custom animation will be greatly appreciated. I need this done in very short span of time.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Did you get a solution yet? May be we can clear the test together :)

Comment: No, I didn't. What test @TezroSolutions?